# AngularJs Directives - directive not loading correctly when passing in local scope when creating a dropdown to filter on a list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

It is easiest to show what I am doing:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r8Evq3fxg6SWHVoGOvIu?p=preview

I want the filter with the directive to work identically to the filter without the directive. I know that I could lose the

```
scope: {
            filterOptions: "=filterOptions"
       },
```

section and this would work, but I want to make this re-usable, which means using this section. I imagine that I need to also somehow pass customFilter in, using '&', so that it is on the global scope.

Can anyone see the errors that I am making with the scope in this directive?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have two problems:

1. You are doing `filterOptions="filterOptions"` instead of `filter-options="filterOptions"`
2. You are not providing `filterItem`.

Overall, this is how your HTML should look like:

```
<my-filter filter-item="filterItem" filter-options="filterOptions"></my-filter>
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnjRGojoJFEToX2hs1IG?p=preview)